# is it advisable to add all class respository links into classpaths?

Tags: java, classpath

My Q is simple! I am working on a JADE framework, along with a few JAVA related platforms and frameworks for different projects. Is it advisable for me to add all the paths where my .class files will be stored in the Environment Variable manually or should a simple -cp command be used in specifying the CLASSPATH manually? Will more/excess entries in the classpath environment variable hinder performance or cause any unforeseen mistakes in future? 
Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a CLASSPATH environment variable on any machine that I work on.  I think it's highly inadvisable.

There are a few problems with it:

1. Not every application you run on your machine will have the same requirements.  Your CLASSPATH environment variable will have to be the union of all.
2. You can't have different versions of JARs in different projects.  If one upgrades, all must upgrade.
3. If you run on another machine, particularly one where you cannot alter environment variables, you're out of luck.

Set the CLASSPATH for every project you create.  For Java EE apps, know how app servers view CLASSPATH and follow suit.

Create a script file for each desktop project if the -cp entry has become oppressive.

Answer (score 1):

Never encountered performance problems with long class paths.

If you are presently working on a project set the classpath accordingly but I don't as I work on many mini-projects simultaneously.

Comment: +1 - "but I don't as I work on many mini-projects simultaneously."  Exactly.